# Site where I can easily see running routes in a city

Tags: running

I will be travelling soon through a couple of cities and I would like to know running routes that others have submitted, i.e. good 5k, 10k routes. What website can I use for this? I tried strava, but could not find search for the routes.

Comment: http://www.mapmyrun.com/

Comment: You could try the travel SE site on here

Comment: https://secure-nikeplus.nike.com/plus/places

Comment: https://www.strava.com/local